# How to check what TLS protocol FuelSDK-PHP is using?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, php, tls

I think the FuelSDK-PHP is using TLSv1, so the question is how to check it.. and how to get it to v1.2, if thats even possible?

This is for PHP not for JAVA, as the other thread is.

Comment: This is PHP not JAVA

Comment: The solution is likely to be the same. PHP relies on some other thing to implement TLS.

Comment: But im pretty sure the changes need to be made within the PHP, and not at the endpoint.